# Cannot find module when compiling under Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have very simple TypeScript app, which compiles fine using webpack, but gives me an error "Build:Cannot find module 'react'" when trying to build in Visual Studio. I'm stuck, any help is appreciated.

package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "react-router-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist/bundle.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.0",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^0.14.49",
    "@types/react-dom": "^0.14.18",
    "@types/react-router": "^2.0.39",
    "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "ts-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.10",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```js
    module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/Index.tsx",
    output: {
        filename: "./dist/bundle.js"
    },

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },

    module: {
        //loaders: [
        //    { test: /\.tsx$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react!ts-loader' }

        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
                loader: "babel-loader!ts-loader"
            },
        ]

    },

    devServer: {
        contentBase: ".",
        host: "localhost",
        port: 8081
    },

    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    },

}
```

tsconfig.json:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

Hello.tsx:

```js
import * as React from "react";

interface IHelloProps { compiler: number }

export class Hello extends React.Component<IHelloProps, {}> {
    render() {
        return <div > Hell no 2!</div >
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything looks fine which makes me wonder. Have you run npm install ?

Comment: if I run 
"npm link typescript" and then "typings install --global --save dt~react" it helps, but after that I seems to always have conflict with my @type folder in node_modules when compiling from webback, and after that have problem with other package, react-router to be exact.

Comment: Try this. Delete your node modules folder then Go to the root folder of your app and run `npm install`....Then give me feedback after that

Comment: Sorry, couldn't get to this lately. I started brand new application, just to have very clean start. Got to the same point. I now realized that I don't want to use typings with new version of typescript, but I'm where I was, compiles from web pack, and cannot find module in Visual Studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it all resolved by installing latest version (2.0.6.0) from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593